# Windows WaitableTimers in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to set windows waitable timers in C++ as follows:

```
#define _SECOND 10000000
void Run()
{
    __int64 qwDueTime= 5 * _SECOND;

    LARGE_INTEGER   liDueTime;
    // Copy the relative time into a LARGE_INTEGER.
    liDueTime.LowPart  = (DWORD) ( qwDueTime & 0xFFFFFFFF );
    liDueTime.HighPart = (LONG)  ( qwDueTime >> 32 );

    SetWaitableTimer(
          CreateWaitableTimer(NULL,FALSE  ,L"2004"),
             &liDueTime,2000,
             (PTIMERAPCROUTINE)TimerFinished,NULL,FALSE );
    cout<<"Second"<<endl;
}
```

where `TimerFinished` is

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerFinished(
    LPVOID lpArg,               // Data value.
    DWORD dwTimerLowValue,      // Timer low value.
    DWORD dwTimerHighValue ) {  // Timer high value.

        cout<<"First"<<endl;
        cout.flush();
 }
```

But unfortunately, TimerFinished is never called..

Any help?

Comment: This link sets qwDueTime to -5 * _SECOND (note the negative) --- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184796

Comment: That will learn 'ya to not check your return codes.

Answer (score 7):

You could find this useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289(v=vs.85).aspx

Quote:

> pDueTime [in]: The time after which
>   the state of the timer is to be set to
>   signaled, in 100 nanosecond intervals.
>   Use the format described by the
>   FILETIME structure. **Positive values
>   indicate absolute time**. Be sure to
>   use a UTC-based absolute time, as the
>   system uses UTC-based time internally.
>   **Negative values indicate relative time**. The actual timer accuracy
>   depends on the capability of your
>   hardware. For more information about
>   UTC-based time, see System Time.

The problem is that you should pass to SetWaitableTimer() a *negative* value (meaning 5 seconds from now), because positive values indicate an *absolute* time. It's the difference between "two days from now" (relative) and "9th of Jan" (absolute).

Comment: Hehe, the rhetorical question is why the callback didn't run even though the due time was expired by 4 centuries.

Comment: Well, I believe it's the same reason your alarm clock will not ring if you set it for a past moment in time.

Answer (score 2):

After your call to SetWaitableTimer you should put that thread (which you are calling SetWaitableTimer in) in alertable state.

To put a thread in alertable state, you need to call SleepEx(), WaitForSingleObjectEx() , WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(), MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() , SignalObjectAndWait() or any other function in same group, which has bAlertable parameter set to TRUE.

Also you can see "Waitable Timers" section which is detailed here: [Timers Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial)